# Why does the DOM include white space between tags?

Tags: dom

```
<div>
   <h1>Heading
```

The first thing in the DOM after the `div` is a text node, rather than the `h1` element. Why does the DOM include this?

(I realise I can select the `h1` with `firstElementChild` rather than `firstChild`, I'm just wondering why the text node is there at all.)

If I apply the style rule `h1:first-child {font-size: 600%;}` it affects the heading, so I assume the "CSS DOM" (if that's a thing) ignores this white space.

Perhaps it has something to do with `white-space: pre;` -if you ever apply this dynamically the DOM has to be ready? But that doesn't seem to fully explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variations in white-space handling ought to be reason enough, but since you've already rejected that as unsatisfactory, I'll give you a different example.

Suppose the markup is this:

```
<section class="test">
    <b>My</b><div>
        <h1>Heading</h1>
    </div>
</section>
```

If we assume that the all white space text node between the `<div>` start tag and the `<h1>` start tag is discarded, then that would be identical to

```
<section class="test">
    <b>My</b><div><h1>Heading</h1>
    </div>
</section>
```

Now see what happens if we add this CSS:

```
.test * { 
   display:inline;
}
```

```css
.test * { 
   display:inline;
   
   /* The below property just helps 
      with visibility of the issue */
   font: 400 1em monospace;
}
```

```html
<section class="test">
    <b>My</b><div>
        <h1>Heading</h1>
    </div>
</section>

<section class="test">
    <b>My</b><div><h1>Heading</h1>
    </div>
</section>
```

Instead of

```
My Heading
```

we get

```
MyHeading
```

So clearly that all white-space text node is necessary and can't be discarded.